# Android - SD Card - Emulator - Ubuntu

Tags: android-emulator

I need to add some files to an **SD card** on **Android Emulator**. I am using **Intellij Idea** on an **Ubuntu system**.

What I 've done so far is:

> 1. Create SD Card image using **mksdcard** command -> *mksdcard -l SD256M 256M ~/sdcard256m.img*.
> 2. Launched Android Emulator with command line option -> *-sdcard ~/sdcard256m.img*

However, I am **unable to add files to the SD Card** using **DDMS - File Explorer** (launched DDMS from command line).

I get the **following error**.

> E/ddms: transfer error: Read-only file system
>   Failed to push testfile.mp3 on emulator-5554: Read-only file system

Also, on the Emulator, under **Settings** > **SD Card & Phone Storage Settings**, I see the fllowing:

> Total Space - Unavailable
>
> Available Space - Unavailable
>
> Mount SD Card - Insert an SD Card for mounting
>
> Format SD Card - Format (erase) the SD Card

I am not sure if the emulator is able to pick up the SD card image that I created.

Please let me know where I am going **wrong**?

**Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the command line parameter while launching the Emulator

> **~/sdcard256m.img**

I had to expand "**~**" and changed it to

> /home/username/sdcard256m.img

The SD Card got detected in the Emulator & I was able to PUSH files through DDMS File Explorer.